# nginx, host multiple wordpress under subdirectories

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I have plenty of wordpress installations under subfolders ordered by client_id and project_id. Those ids are only digits.

Example

```
/wp/000001/0034355
/wp/040000/3450300
...
```

in my nginx I have this rule

```
server {
    root ~/www/wordpress;

    if ($request_uri ~ ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*).*$ ) {
        try_files $uri /$1/$2/index.php?\$query_string;
    }
}
```

this works fine with wordpress but when I try to get access to `/wp-admin` this rules goes to `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Is there any other way to do what I want to do?